# What's the difference between INSERT ... SELECT and SELECT INTO

Tags: postgresql, select, insert

Let's say I have a table `item` and an other one `versionned_item`. From time to time, I want to copy data from `item` to `versionned_item`. What I did is

```
   WITH
     subset AS (SELECT ...)
     INSERT INTO versionned_item SELECT ... FROM subset
```

But in the documentation I came across the `SELECT INTO` statement that seems to do the exact same thing so I am wondering if there are differences / good practices about those 2 kind of inserts.

Comment: `select into` is either used inside PL/pgSQL to store the result of a select in a variable or as a non-standard replacement for `create table .. as select ...`

Comment: A better read of the documentation showed anonymous horse made the best answer. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT INTO is usually used to select specific set of data into a table, esp., during scenarios when the data in the table is the priority and not the constraints. It automatically creates a table if there is no such table already. But, INSERT INTO is used when you already have a table that has specific defined constraints and need to add data from a different table.

Comment: True, trying to `select into` an existing table pops an error out.